# How to get address(city,state, country, zipcode) from BING map api by latitude and longitude?

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

How to get address(city,state, country, zipcode) from BING map api by latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Bing Maps REST Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx)

For your case you have info in this page: [Find a Location by Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)

One example is: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey

Using jquery is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + latitude + ',' + longitude,
    data: {
        o: 'xml',
        key: BingMapsKey
    },
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        //Process the result
    },
    error: function(){
        //Process the error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Shaulin - You are trying to do "reverse geocoding".  Have you tried to use the bing api's described [in the Bing Map Geocode Service API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx)

Hope this helps (if not, maybe you can be more specific with the question).  At the very least, search for "reverse geocoding bing maps" will be helpful.

Good Luck,
Dennis

Comment: I have longitude and latitude values and I need to get full address back based on this values. I will take a look at suggested articles. Thank u